# For loop in VB script TIA portal

Tags: for-loop, vbscript

I just started scripting in VB. Running into a problem with a for loop.
[Picture problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puLHE.png)

I can't find the way to do this in a for loop.. not used to this language.
So I just want:

```
For i = 1 to 8
    Set Bol_i = .... ("Bol_i")
Next
```

What I'm trying to do is to set certain variables (e.g: bol_1, bol_2, bol_3) but instead of just copy and pasting these Set commands I want to do this in a for loop. Where the number values after 'bol_' are the counter in the for loop. I just need to know which signs I need to use... {} or () or "" or '' or [].. I don't seem to find it

Comment: What are you trying to do? What exactly is the problem? Please describe what isn't working and what you've tried already. [Ask].

Comment: Are you sure your tags are right, the pic you attached looks more like vba.  While vb.net and vba share some syntax they are very different tools

Comment: vb.net does not support `Set`. I don't know what this is but it is not vb.net. Please correct your tags.

Comment: You could do this using `ExecuteGlobal` which takes a string and executes it as code. So something like `ExecuteGlobal "Set Bol_" & i & " = HmiRuntime.Screens(""Screen_3"").ScreenItems(""Bol_" & i & """)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the [`ExecuteGlobal` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//342311f1%28v%3dvs.85%29) which will take a string and execute it as code.

Something like this in your loop should work;

```
ExecuteGlobal "Set Bol_" & i & " = HmiRuntime.Screens(""Screen_3"").ScreenItems(""Bol_" & i & """)"
```